# Changing base class of a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to change the base class of a Window that I have added to my project.

Here is some code:

```
public partial class MoviesView : MvvmHelper.Base.ViewBase
{
    public MoviesView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Mvvm:ViewBase x:Class="MvvmHelperUI.Views.MoviesView"
    xmlns:Mvvm="clr-namespace:MvvmHelper.Base"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MoviesView" Height="300" Width="300">
   <Grid>

   </Grid>
</Mvvm:ViewBase>
```

I am receiving the error:

```
The name "ViewBase" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MvvmHelper.Base".
```

And also:

```
The tag 'ViewBase' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MvvmHelper.Base'.
```

The base class, **ViewBase** has no implementation as of yet, it only inherits from **Window**. It definitely exists in the namespace, I have no idea what this issue could be.

It's probably worth mentioning that ViewBase is in a different assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

As ViewBase is in a different assembly, I had to add the assembly declaration in the XAML:

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MvvmHelper.Base;assembly=MvvmHelper"
```

Comment: Also, make sure to build. XAML will mark these as errors until the class has been built.